# How do 'cluster' and 'worker_threads' work in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, v8, node-worker-threads

- Did I understand correctly: If I use `cluster` package, does it mean that 
  a new node instance is created for each created worker?
- What is the difference between `cluster` and `worker_threads` packages?

Answer (score 71):

Effectively what you are differing is *process based* vs *thread based*.  Threads share memory (e.g. `SharedArrayBuffer`) whereas processes don't.  Essentially they are the same thing categorically.

**[cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)**

- One *process* is launched on each CPU and can communicate via [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).
- Each process has it's own memory with it's own Node (v8) instance. Creating tons of them may create memory issues.
- Great for spawning many HTTP servers that share the same port b/c the <strike>master</strike> main process will multiplex the requests to the child processes.

**[worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html?worker_threads_worker_threads#worker_threads_worker_threads)**

- One *process* total
- Creates multiple threads with each thread having one Node instance (one event loop, one JS engine).  Most Node API's are available to each thread except a few.  So essentially Node is embedding itself and creating a new thread.
- Shares memory with other threads (e.g. `SharedArrayBuffer`)
- Great for CPU intensive tasks like processing data or accessing the file system.  Because NodeJS is single threaded, synchronous tasks can be made more efficient with workers

Comment: For worker_threads: One process total. Does that mean spread across multiple V8 instances ?

Comment: Each worker thread will have it's own V8 instance and Event Loop.  This is how you gain parallelism. They call it a V8 isolate.  Effectively, this is an independent instance of the V8 runtime that has its own JS heap and a microtask queue. Each Node.js worker thread can thus run it's code in isolation without sharing their heaps.  Communication; however, occurs through a message channel between child and parent.

Comment: @snewcomer
Wouldn't worker threads involve in deadlock situations as they share memory? If yes, then wouldn't it slow down the CPU performance?

Comment: Why do you strikethrough master ?

Comment: @SarimJavaidKhan They do not share memory. data passed over channels is copied, but this is still way more efficient than JSON stringify/parse for IPC.